# Unable to login to wordpress site with Python3 Requests Module

Tags: python, wordpress, http, authentication, python-requests

I'm writing a python bot to scrape a wordpress site but I need to be logged in to access some of the resources I want. Here is the code:

```
# username, password, and wp_login is defined above

with requests.Session() as s:
    # store any initial cookies in the session
    s.get(wp_login)

    datas={
        'log':username, 'pwd':password, 'wp-submit':'Log In',
        'redirect-to':'', 'testcookie':'1'
    }

    # successful or unsuccessful login returns a 302 so I have to not allow
    # redirects or I can't view the response header to check for the cookies I need
    response = s.post(wp_login, data=datas, allow_redirects=False)

    print(response.status_code)
    print()
    print(response.request.headers)
    print()
    print(response.headers)
```

Here is the output

```
302

{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cookie': '__cfduid=[REDACTED]', 'Content-Length': '57', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

{'Date': 'Mon, 30 Sep 2019 06:13:43 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Powered-By': 'PHP/5.6.32', 'X-Redirect-By': 'WordPress', 'Location': 'https://________/wp-login.php', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '51e40d72d87c9691-SJC'}
```

I should be receiving a cookie on successful login and the redirect in the response header should be to the home page. So authentication is failing, and I don't understand why?

Edit: A successful POST request, when viewed in Chrome Developer tools, has the following data string:

```
log=[username]&pwd=[password]&wp-submit=Log+In&redirect_to=&testcookie=1
```

Comment: Yes, because authentication is failing. I submit a POST request to wp-login.php with my data, it's going to respond 302 regardless. On successful login it sends me a cookie saying I'm authenticated and redirects to the home page. On unsuccessful login it redirects me to wp-login.php so that I can try to sign in again.

Comment: hi there - good day dear Holden Nelson - i am very very glad to hear from you: thank you for stepping up the plate and supporting us in this situation. I am very very glad that we are a great ans strong commuznity., Dear Holden - keep up your great: work it rocks!!! Many thanks for all you did!!